# Can't get the real time difference between two times in hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

When I run this code it works fine, but it gives me the wrong time difference

```
import datetime

start_time = "02:30 PM"
end_time = "01:30 AM"

firstTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time , "%I:%M %p")
print(f"Datetime Start Time is {firstTime}")

endTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time , "%I:%M %p")
print(f"Datetime End Time Is {endTime}")

deltaTime = firstTime-endTime

print(f"Time Difference is {deltaTime.total_seconds()/(60*60)} hours")
```

When I check the time difference in google it says 11 hours, but this code returns 13 hours why is that?

Comment: Usually when counting a difference, especially with times, it makes more sense to do `end - start`. You did `deltaTime = firstTime-endTime`. That is a *part* of your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can handle that by adding a simple (`if.. else`) statement with [`datetime.timedetla`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to shift the *difference* by one day in case your `end_time` falls on the next day.

```
deltaTime = endTime - firstTime

timeDiff = deltaTime + timedelta(days=1) if deltaTime.days < 0 else deltaTime
```

Output :

```
print(f"Time difference is {timeDiff.total_seconds()/3600} hours")
#Time difference is 11.0 hours
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct.

It will calculate form the same day. Since you have not mentined the start day.

```
Datetime Start Time is 1900-01-01 14:30:00
Datetime End Time Is 1900-01-01 01:30:00
Time Difference is 13.0 hours
```

So, when you take the difference between `01:30` and `14:30` on the same day that is `1900-01-01` the difference will be 13 hours as `01:30` comes before `14:30`

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have to do with your subtraction `deltaTime = firstTime-endTime`

Basically if count from the endTime to firstTime it's doing a 14:30 - 1:30 instead of doing a 1:30 - 14:30

I suggest you change the order of the math count and then format the answer because the value of deltaTime will be `-1 day, 11:00:00`